# Java collection with Incompatible types error

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

So I have this function, and it's not compiling. What is the problem?

The compiling error is 
Line 4: error: incompatible types

```
public List<List<Integer>> myfunc(int[] num) {

        List<List<Integer>> r = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();  //line 4
        return r;
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It should be `List<List<Integer>> r = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`

Comment: heres some explanation why to do so :p

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: It could also be: `List<? extends List<Integer>> r = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` isn't a `List<List<Integer>>`, for the same reason that an `ArrayList<Apple>` isn't a `List<Fruit>`, and it's fairly easy to given an example of why that's the case:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 

// This won't work, but imagine that it did...
List<List<Integer>> lists = arrayLists;

// This is fine - a LinkedList<Integer> is a List<Integer>
lists.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());

// This should be fine too
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = arrayLists.get(0);
```

So what happens at that last line? Somehow `arrayList` would have a reference to a `LinkedList`, even though its type is `ArrayList<Integer>`. Eek!

That's a demonstration of why the code wouldn't be safe if it were allowed - which is why it's *not* allowed. A simpler example is with fruits as I mentioned earlier:

```
List<Apple> apples = new List<Apples>();
// Again, not allowed
List<Fruit> fruit = apples;

// Because this would be odd...
fruit.Add(new Banana());

// It's a Banapple!
Apple apple = apples.get(0);
```

There are various things you *could* do here - but the simplest is probably just to create an `ArrayList<List<Integer>>` instead of an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.

Comment: Lol I'm going to remember 'Banapple'!! Thank you so much for the thorough explaination!!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is matching the element type of the declared `List` with the element type of the created instance of `ArrayList`. They should be the same:

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> r = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Or

```
List<List<Integer>> r = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

The second one is better since the element type is an interface.